# Dynamic Dependent Parameters in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am looking to create a report based on two parameters, VENDOR and PONUMBERS.

I would like to create the report in such a way that on loading report when we choose a vendor

as First parameter it should show just the PONUMBERS for that vendor on second parameter. Is it possible in Crystal Reports ?

Comment: Please tag your question once with `crystal-reports` and once with the actual version that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes its possible...

While creating a parameters use dynamic parameters not static from the dropdown

select first parameter as `Vendor` and second parmeter as `PONumber`.

Now when you refresh the report second parameter will be filtered as per the selection of first parameter.

Comment: I think i figured it out. I created a Parameter and added Vendor Field to it but did not click generate parameter. Than on the next line I added second Field PO Number and clicked Generate Parameter. So Now I get the option to choose vendor and also it shows me only the POs for that vendor .. :)